# CMake - Linking Pre-built Libraries to C# Project

Tags: c#, cmake

I am building a C# library with CMake.  The library depends on an already built library (.dll).

I cannot seem to get library to link in to my library.

I have tried using `target_link_libraries(mylib ${external_lib})`.
I have also tried brute-forcing a `/reference:${external_lib}` as a compile option (but CMake removes it at build time).

How can I accomplish this with CMake?

Normally in a VS C# project file you would add:

```
<Reference Include="somelibrary">
    <HintPath>path/to/some/library</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/release/3.8.html#id4), you should be able to set `VS_DOTNET_REFERENCE_<refname>` property on `mylib` target, like this:

```
set_target_properties(mylib PROPERTIES 
    VS_DOTNET_REFERENCE_somelibrary "/path/to/libs/somelibrary.dll")
```

Be sure to not only provide the path to the library, but also the full library name `somelibrary.dll`.