# Add DLL reference to CMake based C# project

Tags: c#, cmake

I am generating an C# Wpf project using CMake. I followed the following example https://github.com/bemehiser/cmake_csharp_wpf_example/blob/master/Example/CMakeLists.txt

My question is: How can add an 3rd party .NET DLL reference to this project using CMake ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake - Linking Pre-built Libraries to C# Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50769548/cmake-linking-pre-built-libraries-to-c-sharp-project) | Note: Just used the linked answer myself successfully.

Answer (score 6):

I'm adding this detailed answer because currently there are quite a number of misleading examples on high-ranking webpages. The answer from [squareskittles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56469566/7200132) below is correct but does not include a detailed discussion of potential pitfalls. This is what my answer tries to give.

For setting the Visual Studio managed project .NET references (like `WindowsBase`), it is best to use the cmake target property [VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES.html). In cmake versions up until 3.22.4, it is important to specify multiple references as a list, not individually. Newer cmake seems not to have this limitation any more (thanks to jasal for pointing this out), but it may still be a good choice to specify multiple references as a list. So it is correct to use either `"PresentationCore;WindowsBase;..."`, or use a cmake list like in the example at the bottom of this post. It is however *not* correct to add multiple references individually, like often seen on the web:

```
# this is incorrect, and will only add the first reference, not all:
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES
    "PresentationCore"
    "WindowsBase"
    ...)
```

To add a binary Visual Studio managed project .NET reference, it is recommended to use one cmake target property [VS_DOTNET_REFERENCE_refname](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VS_DOTNET_REFERENCE_refname.html) for every binary reference. It is required that the `<refname>` is replaced with the reference file name, without extension. It is *not* correct to specify a different `<refname>` for the reference:

```
# this is incorrect, because the refname "mythriftlib" and the
# reference file name "Thrift" of the DLL mismatch:
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES VS_DOTNET_REFERENCE_mythriftlib
     "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin/Thrift.dll")
```

Last, not least, I prefer to use `set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} ...)` over the equally valid `set_properties(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} ...)`. Whichever you choose, it is nice to be consistent in your `CMakeLists.txt`.

Here is a correct, full example to get you started:

```
project(WPFGui VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES CSharp)

include(CSharpUtilities)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    App.config
    App.xaml
    App.cs
    MainWindow.xaml
    MainWindow.cs
    Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
    Properties/Resources.Designer.cs
    Properties/Resources.resx
    Properties/Settings.Designer.cs
    Properties/Settings.settings)

csharp_set_designer_cs_properties(
    Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
    Properties/Resources.Designer.cs
    Properties/Resources.resx
    Properties/Settings.Designer.cs
    Properties/Settings.settings)

csharp_set_xaml_cs_properties(
    App.xaml
    App.cs
    MainWindow.xaml
    MainWindow.cs)

set_source_files_properties(App.xaml PROPERTIES
    VS_XAML_TYPE "ApplicationDefinition")

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    DOTNET_TARGET_FRAMEWORK_VERSION "v4.6.1")

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE)

LIST(APPEND VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES "Microsoft.CSharp")
LIST(APPEND VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES "PresentationCore")
LIST(APPEND VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES "PresentationFramework")
LIST(APPEND VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES "System")
LIST(APPEND VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES "System.Xaml")
LIST(APPEND VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES "System.Xml")
LIST(APPEND VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES "System.Xml.Linq")
LIST(APPEND VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES "WindowsBase")

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES "${VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES}"
    VS_DOTNET_REFERENCE_Thrift "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin/Thrift.dll")
```

Comment: How to set Private to False in csproj file. I would like to not copy the third party dll to output directory after building.

Comment: Dear @PawełIwaneczko I'm sorry but its better if you ask a new question for "How to set Private to False in csproj file" because its a different topic. All the best for your coding!

Comment: Thanks, I don't need to any more. I found the solution: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VS_DOTNET_REFERENCEPROP_refname_TAG_tagname.html

Comment: "It is important to specify multiple references as a list, not individually." In CMake 3.22.4 this works fine.

Answer (score 2):

As an example, you can try the following for a 3rd-party library called `MyLibrary.dll`:

```
add_executable(MyTarget
    #  ... list source files here ...
)

# Add the reference to the 3rd-party library: MyLibrary
set_property(TARGET MyTarget PROPERTY 
    VS_DOTNET_REFERENCE_MyLibrary "/path/to/the/libs/MyLibrary.dll")
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it's also possible to add a bunch of DLLs in one go without specifying reference names like this:

```
add_library(mylib SHARED)
set_property(TARGET mylib PROPERTY VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES "C:\\a\\b\\c\\lib1.dll;C:\\d\\e\\f\\wow.lib2.dll")
```

Reference names get generated based on DLL's file name like `lib1` and `wow.lib2`.