# Using a DLL in a Cmake C# project

Tags: c#, dll, cmake

I'm trying to use CMake to build a C# DLL. For this, I need to add a third party .dll to the project, so I can use some functions of it that I need.

The problem is, I can access the library, not even

```
using Namespace;
```

works, as the `Namespace` is not recognized.

```
# cmake version
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

# project
project ("VILAPI" CSharp)

# include directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

# source and library output paths and directories
set(SRCS_VILAPI "./src/main.cs")
set(OUT_DIR ${CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY}/bin)

# actual building process
add_library (${project} SHARED ${SRCS_VILAPI})

set_property(TARGET ${project} PROPERTY DOTNET_TARGET_FRAMEWORK_VERSION "v4.0")
set_property(TARGET ${project} PROPERTY WIN32_EXECUTABLE FALSE)
set_property(TARGET ${project} PROPERTY VS_CONFIGURATION_TYPE ClassLibrary)
set_property(TARGET ${project} PROPERTY VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES
    "System"
    "./lib/Vector.CANoe.TFS.dll"
)

set_target_properties(${project} PROPERTIES ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${OUT_DIR})
set_target_properties(${project} PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${OUT_DIR})
```

CMake doesn't throw an error. I've also tried to add it the following way:

```
set_property(TARGET ${project} PROPERTY     VS_DOTNET_REFERENCE_Vector.CANoe.TFS.dll "./lib/Vector.CANoe.TFS.dll")
```

which was suggested in an answer on stackoverflow, but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

For third-party DLL references, you should be using [`VS_DOTNET_REFERENCE_<refname>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VS_DOTNET_REFERENCE_refname.html) property. The [`VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES.html#prop_tgt:VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES) property is typically used for Visual Studio managed references only.

Your `set_property()` command using the `VS_DOTNET_REFERENCE_<refname>` property was close, it just needs a small change:

```
set_property(TARGET ${project} PROPERTY VS_DOTNET_REFERENCE_Vector.CANoe.TFS "./lib/Vector.CANoe.TFS.dll")
```

The `<refname>` should refer to the DLL file name **without** the `.dll` file extension (i.e. only `Vector.CANoe.TFS`). See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56469566/3987854) for another example.